# Enter ID instead of name on submit (form)

Tags: php, mysql

In my users_subjects table, I have a user ID and a subject ID. When a user (of admin level) creates a subject they select from a drop down menu a project. Here is the select query to draw up appropriate values:

```
$sql = "SELECT users_subjects.users_subjectsid, subjects.subjectn FROM subjects JOIN users_subjects on subjects.subjectid = users_subjects.userid ";
```

And for the  tag with the dropdown menu, I have this:

```
<?php echo $row['subjectn']?>
```

I have tried submitting the form with 'subjectid' here instead and the subject ID is stored successfully in my users_subjects table. However, the user needs to see the subject names (IDs arent exactly user-friendly!)

Answer (score 2):

```
<option value="projectidgoeshere">Project name goes here</option>
```